# Can't mount filesystem by offset

Tags: mount, hfs+

I'm having trouble trying to mount a filesystem. Basically, if I mount `/dev/sdc1`, it works perfectly. But if I mount `/dev/sdc` with a byte offset, it fails. The filesystem is HFS+ (formatted using an actual iMac).

```
root# fdisk -l /dev/sdc

Disk /dev/sdc: 320.1 GB, 320072932864 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142447 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1              63      128519       64228+  af  HFS / HFS+
root# mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
root# echo $?
0
root# umount /mnt
root# mount --ro -o offset=32256,sizelimit=6576994 /dev/sdc /mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop20,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so
root# dmesg | tail
[164258.208493] hfs: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[164398.983651] hfs: invalid secondary volume header
[164398.983654] hfs: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[164404.235785] hfs: invalid secondary volume header
[164404.235787] hfs: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[164407.461400] hfs: invalid secondary volume header
[164407.461404] hfs: unable to find HFS+ superblock
```

What the heck am I doing wrong here?

P.S. The offsets seem to match the output from `fdisk`, so that's not the problem.

**EDIT** Added `fdisk` output.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' Done.

Comment: It probably doesn't help, but the string "unable to find HFS+ superblock" appears on line 410 in `fs/hfsplus/super.c` in the kernel tree. (Yes, I'm reading the Linux kernel source code in a desperate attempt to find out what going on!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was broken in OpenSUSE 12.1, but when I updated my PC to OpenSUSE 13.1, the problem simply stopped existing. Weird, but true! Must have been a kernel bug or something...